# Почему не подключается rxjs6 из cdn?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Подскажите пожалуйста почему [этот простейший скрипт](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lgtwb01/4/) выводит ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Rx is not defined

Дело в том, что я подключил rxjs6 из cdn. Но получается, что она не подключилась.

js:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(
  // scan (reduce) to a stream of counts
  scan(count => count + 1, 0)
  // Set the count on an element each time it changes
).subscribe(count => document.querySelector('#count').innerHTML = count);
```

Comment: А где собственно код подключения библиотеки?

Comment: @RifmaMan в первом предложении есть ссылка на jsfiddle

Comment: Посмотрите [на пример](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/installation.md) в самом низу страницы и сделайте аналогично объявление функции с константами

Comment: @RifmaMan помогло)

Comment: Отлично! Думаю можно закрывать вопрос ;-)